# How do you actually play an AVAssetTrack, not an AVURLAsset?

Tags: avfoundation, avasset

Say you have a small video file

```
let p = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "small", ofType: "mp4")
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: p!)
```

you can easily make it a player item and play it ..

```
let pi = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
av.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: pi)
```

Alternately, you can make it an AVURLAsset and then get one of the tracks

## AVAssetTrack

```
 asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
 let tracks:[AVAssetTrack] = asset!.tracks
 print(tracks.count)
 let track:AVAssetTrack = tracks[2]
```

How then ....... do you play one of the tracks??

how do you play an AVAssetTrack ??

Comment: You can create an `AVMutableComposition` and a `AVMutableCompositionTrack`, insert the `AVAssetTrack` into the latter and then create an `AVPlayerItem` from the composition (it's a subclass of `AVAsset`). However if you're just trying to silence the audio in a video, you can simply mute the `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Ah, gotchya.  Good one.  So you have to make a `AVMutableComposition` - there's no sense in which you can just tell it "play that track".  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that shows how you can create an `AVMutableComposition` containing only your desired track and then play the composition as you would play any `AVAsset` because, perhaps surprisingly considering the name, it is one:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let track = asset.tracks[1]  // or whatever

let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

try! compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: track, at: .zero)

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)  // play me in your AVPlayer
```

**N.B.** in real life `tracks` and `duration` should probably be loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Ah - you saved everyone else (not me of course) from working that out  :)  Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way :

```
let video = AVURLAsset(url : url)
let track = video!.tracks[0]
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: track.asset!)
```

Comment: sorry, what is "video" ?  you may misunderstand the question ..

Comment: sorry i forgot to define 'video'